# Using minus in C#

Tags: c#

I want to use `-` in the code below but Visual Studio doesn't let me to use it and gives "error, unexpected character".

```
    Name = objFileInfo.Name.Substring(0,  
        objFileInfo.Name.Length – objFileInfo.Extension.Length);
```

Comment: Could you please post the error message?

Comment: What keyboard do you have? The minus on the UK keyboard is to the right of `0`.

Comment: Fun facts; since the character is an en-dash – U+2013 (not a minus as people have said, if you want to do a truly unambiguous minus [in a document, not a C♯ program, obviously] use − U+2212), in many usages this would indicate a range of numbers, starting at objFileInfo.Name.Length and ending at objFileInfo.Extension.Length. Imagine the confusion possibilities of defining a numeric range based on it. Luckily, Microsoft only rarely even spell the language C♯ rather than C# so I think we're safe.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is not a minus you are using:

Yours (char 8211, a math minus):

```
–
```

Minus (shorter, char 45 ascii, a dash which represents minus in C#):

```
-
```

Try copy the c# minus I use above and it will work :-)

Comment: ok it solved.thanks.i copied that code and the problem was this

Comment: Well, the 'minus' on the keyboard is sort of a hyphen/minus crossover. There is a specialized minus character defined in unicode. However, he's trying to use an *en dash*.

Comment: @Thorarin I have clarified it now.

Answer (score 2):

In C# (and I imagine almost any other programming language), the minus sign is simply represented by an ASCII dash, or hyphen-minus, which is a single keystroke on standard ASCII keyboards:

```
-
```

Not the mathematical minus symbol, which you're using:

```
−
```

Answer (score 0):

That character... whatever character it is... is not a minus (ascii code 45).

Comment: It is a mathematical minus sign, but not the one on our ASCII keyboards (ASCII code 45 as you say).

Comment: @Bolt yar.  Seems he copypasted some code from a blog.  Never a pleasant experience.